# Is it possible to exclude the calling class using slf4j?

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j

I'm writing a logging utility to do standard log lines rather than having to write them for every method. I want to exclude this utility class so the original calling class is logged instead of logging LogUtility every time.

Like this [Java Logging: show the source line number of the caller (not the logging helper method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486233/java-logging-show-the-source-line-number-of-the-caller-not-the-logging-helper) but with slf4j instead of log4j.

I'm using the Spring Boot platform and using slf4j so it's portable.